# java eclipse juno error poping SYNTAX error even though its correct help me out

Tags: java

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the answer" + sum, "the title",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Its my code in *eclipse* *Juno* giving `SYNTAX` *error*.

Comment: Hmm.. You could try a Project > Clean. Otherwise that's strange, it works for me. Edit: Maybe it's surrounding code.

Comment: Does it say anything more than just "syntax error"?

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the answer"+sum, "the title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE)` seem to be right. But check whether have you imported the class `JOptionPane` and do a clean of your project . If the error still persists consider checking your build path whether have you included proper JRE library.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for -1. please

Comment: Oops :-) I was editing my answers dude

Comment: Am not able to remove my -1 since you last edited it

Answer (score 1):

Restart Eclipse in clean mode by `eclispe -clean` in command mode. Solves all kinda issues like this. I face a few. This has helped me.